# How to Implement ' Search Google for "Text" ' like functionality in an Eclipse Editor

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

In web browsers like chrome, there is a popup menu called **search Google for "some text"** available to search for a particular string or word in a webpage.how to implement the same functionality in an eclipse editor.is it possible to select some text in an eclipse editor and open/search that text in a web browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here in github they can given the source code for **SublimeText package in pytho**n refer the functionality and try in rpc.

[google-search](https://github.com/nwjlyons/google-search)